# Pitch and roll in iOS to the same ones in android?

Tags: android, ios, rotation, latitude-longitude, pitch

In iOS:

> A pitch is a rotation around a lateral axis that passes through the
> device from side to side.
>
> A roll is a rotation around a longitudinal axis that passes through the device from its top to bottom.

Additionally in iOS pitch is [-90, 90] and roll is [-180 180].

In android:

> Pitch, rotation around x-axis (-180 to 180), with positive values when
> the z-axis moves toward the y-axis.
>
> Roll, rotation around the x-axis (-90 to 90) increasing as the device
> moves clockwise.

[source for android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

How to convert iOS -> android characteristics if they are even defined in different intervals?

Comment: I suspect that this is a documentation bug, I believe - `Roll, rotation around the z-axis (-90 to 90) increasing as the device moves clockwise.`

Comment: Yes, it seems a documentation bug. But I think in reality pitch is around the x axis, roll is around y and yaw is around z - for both platforms. But in iOS and android pitch and roll have various intervals.

Comment: Yep, you're right, my suggested fix for the bug has a bug :)  Roll is indeed around y.

Comment: thanks but I still have the problem of converting [-180 180] [-90 90] to [-90 90] [-180 180]